# how can change first page from publisher to store and redirect the non https address to https

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am using wso2 apim 2.6 and analytics 2.6.
I have two problem. 
first I want to change the default page from publisher address to store address.
for example when I write just the  address (sample : https://example.com) by default it goes to https://example.com/publisher . I want to change this default to https://example.com/store .

and my second problem is about redirecting the non https address (sample: example.com/store) to https one (sample : https://example.com/store). now when I write example.com get error on page and doesn't load.

in every samples I use https://example.com instead of  address

Comment: Once again please remove this url unless you've secured it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the default context is publisher in API Manager. That is why you are redirecting to the publisher. You can change this to store by following https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Directing+the+Root+Context+to+the+API+Store

You can rewrite http traffic to https in the load balancer side. Sample can be found in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+the+Proxy+Server+and+the+Load+Balancer for Nginx.